# Go-Web3 Transaction failing due to Insufficient funds for gas* price + value

Tags: go, ethereum, go-ethereum, binance-smart-chain

my transaction is failing for some reason due to  `{"code":-32000,"message":"insufficient funds for gas * price + value"}`

I am executing a pancakeswap transaction to swap a token for bnb. I have the gas set to 5 gwei and I have web3 getting the gas estimate that will be used.

I have more than enough bnb in my account to pay for the gas but I keep getting this error. Can anyone advise on how to solve this? I have also tried to send a transaction calling the approve function on a smart contract but I am getting the same error.

`Gas:29406`
`Gas Price:5000000000`
`Value: 0`

`Gas*Price+value= 147030000000000`

`Wallet Balance 26270052976800394`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How do you get the gas estimate from web3

Answer (score 0):

```
let gas = await web3.eth.estimateGas({
        "from": fromAddress,
    });
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.